# Permitir caracteres especial como @#%&-+()/*"':;!?|~{}[]_ en password

Tags: php, regex

¿Que expresión regular puedo usar para permitir caracteres como estos `@#%&-+()/*"':;!?~|{}[]_` en php?

Comment: Puedes especificar como quieres realizar la validación del password?

Comment: mediante php y ajax, con un pattern de input.

Comment: perdon sino me explico bien

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Con esta expresión regular te obliga a:

La contraseña debe tener al entre 8 y 16 caracteres, al menos un dígito, al menos una minúscula, al menos una mayúscula y al menos un caracter no alfanumérico.

```
^(?=.*\d)(?=.*[\u0021-\u002b\u003c-\u0040])(?=.*[A-Z])(?=.*[a-z])\S{8,16}$
```

el código en PHP

```
if (preg_match('/^(?=.*\d)(?=.*[\u0021-\u002b\u003c-\u0040])(?=.*[A-Z])(?=.*[a-z])\S{8,16}$/', $cadenaok))
{
    return true;
}
```

Comment: muchas gracias por tu ayuda.

Comment: Genial respuesta @Jose, lo has echo tu o de la documentación? http://w3.unpocodetodo.info/utiles/regex-ejemplos.php?type=psw para dejar el link ahí :)

Comment: Lo copie de un fichero que tengo de funciones, puede ser que en su día lo tomase de esa página, pero después de tres años con mi fichero de funciones ni me acuerdo

Comment: Muchas gracias por tu aporte (Y) me sirvio a la perfeccion